# Separate ul / ol blocks

Tags: css

Is it possible to continue the numbering in separate ul / ol blocks with css?
1 2 3 4 5 6 ....

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this property?

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/

Something like this, you could modify it onto the ordered list only, use **counter-increment**.

More info of the usage here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment

Comment: yea i saw first link example.. but i wanted to do this with css.. i think its impossible .. :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
// use start number you want as below
<ol start="50">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```